# Rails - Trying to display current page number

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, parameters, instance-variables

**Routes**

```
match '/user/:username/:pagenum' => 'vines#user'
```

**Controller**

```
    def user
        @username = params[:username]
        @page = params[:pagenum]
        respond_to do |format|
            format.html
            format.json
        end
    end
```

**View**

```
<% if @page == 1 %>

    page 1

<% elsif @page == 2 %>

    page 2

<% end %>
```

Why is the page not displaying the words 'page 1' or 'page 2' when I visit the url `http://127.0.0.1:3000/user/randomperson/1` or `http://127.0.0.1:3000/user/randomperson/2`

Comment: What are you going to do with 20 pages? String 20 `elsif` together?  Should use `<%= @page %>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you have strings in params. Try to use

```
@page = params[:pagenum].to_i
```